# show location of the coordinates on the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to enter X and Y to two inputs then show me the location of the coordinates on the page
I tried hard but failed
My page size is large when I enter the coordinates the page should scroll to show the location because the length and width of the body is larger than the screen:

```
body {
 width: 5000px;
 height: 6000px;            
}
```

Thanks to friends for the help

Comment: What do you mean by "the page should rotate to show the location"? The answer, and a pending edit, assume you mean "the page should **scroll** to show the location", but that's a very different word. Also, you say you "tried hard", but I see no attempt here. Please [edit] your question to show your attempt(s). You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar) to use an interface much like jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I made you a small example that takes you to the coordinates **X** and **Y** you specified through the `prompt()`.

Method `scrollTo()` is used for scrolling. This is a simple example, but you can improve and refine it.

```js
let x = prompt("Enter X");
let y = prompt("Enter Y");
let coordinate_x = parseInt(x);
let coordinate_y = parseInt(y);

window.scrollTo(coordinate_x, coordinate_y);
```

```css
body {
 width: 5000px;
 height: 6000px; 
 background-color: green;
}
```