# How can i move the "camera" of the canvas in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm making a 3D game which guides you across skyboxes, and what I need to do is for it to detect when the user presses a key, and move the camera that way (I'm fine with standard WASD).

How could I do this?

JavaScript:

```
var world = document.getElementById("boxDiv");
var x;
var y;

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e)
{
x = e.clientX;
y = e.clientY;
y = -y;
world.style.transform = "translateZ(600px) rotateX("+y+"deg) rotateY("+x+"deg)";
});
```

This code is for the skybox generation.

Comment: will it help you? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65480674/show-location-of-the-coordinates-on-the-page/65481160#65481160

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Sadly not, sorry.

Comment: but you can take this principle as a basis

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Sadly not, because as soon as I put that code in, the game stopped working. The prompt didn't appear, and I couldn't move the camera. I've found another way of ging through each level, and I've put a question up for it too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of the best minimal reproducible examples on [WASD controls on three.js](https://codepen.io/Fyrestar/pen/oNxERMr)

[image]

Kudos for the author [Fyrestar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5679432/fyrestar)

Relevant code is below:

```js
// author: Fyrestar <info@mevedia.com>
var camera, scene, renderer, mesh, goal, keys, follow;

var time = 0;
var newPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

var stop = 1;
var DEGTORAD = 0.01745327;
var temp = new THREE.Vector3;
var dir = new THREE.Vector3;
var a = new THREE.Vector3;
var b = new THREE.Vector3;
var coronaSafetyDistance = 0.3;
var velocity = 0.0;
var speed = 0.0;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
    camera.position.set( 0, .3, 0 );
    
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    
    goal = new THREE.Object3D;
    follow = new THREE.Object3D;
    follow.position.z = -coronaSafetyDistance;
    mesh.add( follow );
    
    goal.add( camera );
    scene.add( mesh );
 

    
    var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper( 40, 40 );
    scene.add( gridHelper );
    
    scene.add( new THREE.AxesHelper() );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
  
keys = {
    a: false,
    s: false,
    d: false,
    w: false
  };
  
  document.body.addEventListener( 'keydown', function(e) {
    
    const key = e.code.replace('Key', '').toLowerCase();
    if ( keys[ key ] !== undefined )
      keys[ key ] = true;
    
  });
  document.body.addEventListener( 'keyup', function(e) {
    
    const key = e.code.replace('Key', '').toLowerCase();
    if ( keys[ key ] !== undefined )
      keys[ key ] = false;
    
  });

}


function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    
  speed = 0.0;
  
  if ( keys.w )
    speed = 0.01;
  else if ( keys.s )
    speed = -0.01;

  velocity += ( speed - velocity ) * .3;
  mesh.translateZ( velocity );

  if ( keys.a )
    mesh.rotateY(0.05);
  else if ( keys.d )
    mesh.rotateY(-0.05);
        
  
  a.lerp(mesh.position, 0.4);
  b.copy(goal.position);
  
    dir.copy( a ).sub( b ).normalize();
    const dis = a.distanceTo( b ) - coronaSafetyDistance;
    goal.position.addScaledVector( dir, dis );
    goal.position.lerp(temp, 0.02);
    temp.setFromMatrixPosition(follow.matrixWorld);
    
    camera.lookAt( mesh.position );
    
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```